# Asp.net gridview rowupdated event e.Tow.RowType type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have some code in GridView1_RowDataBound event for html design of table :

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        }
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TableCellCollection cell = e.Row.Cells;
            cell[0].Attributes.Add("data-title", "");
            cell[1].Attributes.Add("data-title", "Product"  

        }
```

After row update I need do this again but I can't. Because RowUpdated EventArgs has no Row property. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the GridView rows outside the RowDataBound event also.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    TableCellCollection cell = row.Cells;
    cell[0].Attributes.Add("data-title", "");
    cell[1].Attributes.Add("data-title", "Product");
}
```

You can access the header row with this

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("data-title", "");
```

Comment: Yeah right. Thank you but it doest work for header type.

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        }

Comment: Updated my answer. You can access the header row also.

Comment: I changed your answer a bit. 
 I removed if statement  " if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)"  and just used  :  GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

Of course your answer was right. Thank you